# Unknown provider: ngTagsInputProvider <- ngTagsInput

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, ng-tags-input

I injected the 2.1.1 version ngtagsinput like this into my controller:

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope','$http','ngTagsInput', function($scope,$http){
}])
```

***NOTE: TESTED! add ngTagsInput into the function() will not make a difference...**

I loaded the ngtagsinput lib after angularjs lib.

I wonder what else I could test to resolve the error of:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngTagsInputProvider <- ngTagsInput
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$injector/unpr?p0=ngTagsInputProvider%20%3C-%20ngTagsInput
```

Don't get me wrong, I know basically this provider is not detected.

but my lib is found (did not report 404), I saw ngTagsInput used in its library....

So, its really bugging me the same solution no more works for this lib! What's special about this lib and why this error is there while I met all the standard to fix it?

Comment: add `ngTagsInput` to your function: `function($scope, $http, ngTagsInput){`

Comment: @Matt Way Tried. It did not work. the same

Comment: and add `ngTagsInput` to the module requires array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you have tried to inject `ngTagsInput` into your controller, while you should be injecting it into your module as a dependency. For example:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngTagsInput'])
```

*note module, not controller*

You can see as per the creators example: https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput#example

---

This happens because there are multiple types of injection used in angular. When you declare a module, you need to specify which other modules are available to use within your module.

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

When you inject into say a controller, you are basically saying that you want to use a particular object inside it. That object must be a part of your module to be valid. For a third party library, this usually means adding it as a module dependency (as above), and then injecting any object that is part of that library into your controllers and services.

Comment: Oh wow!!!! Why is this happening though??? Why this service in bind toward a module but can not be applied to a controller?? Plz elaborate, its very interesting!

Comment: @Chen ngTagsInput is a **directive**, not a service. You must use it as a custom HTML element in your markup. Check out the project's [Getting started](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/gettingstarted) page for more information.

Comment: @Michael Benford Does it means that a directive can't be apply to a controller but a module only?

Comment: @Chen No. Directives can only be used in HTML. You may want to check out the docs on [modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) and [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: @Michael Benford Sry, what I mean is that one need to inject another service into app module in order to use the directive sometimes, no?